# Flex pass event handler and add it to dynamically created object inside itemrenderer

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, tree, mxml, itemrenderer

I have a `Tree`, which has an `itemRenderer`.  On the `itemRenderer`, driven by the XML conditions, objects are created dynamically  and added as a children to nodes.
These new objects shall trigger an event handler ( some click events mostly ).

- How do I pass the event handler to the tree and later to the dynamically created new objects inside `itemRendere`?

Something like:

```
<mx:Tree x="534" y="49" newObjectsOnClick="newObjectsOnClickHandler">
```

Comment: If you need the click on item event why don;t you use onItemClick event thrown by the tree ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use event bubbling for events dispatched from item renderers.

So create a custom event as the following:

```
public class MyEvent extends Event
{
    public static const SOME_ACTION_PERFORMED:String = "someActionPerformed";
    public function MyEvent(type:String)
    {
        // The second parameter is for bubbling!
        super(type, true, false);
    }

    override public function clone():Event
    {
        return new MyEvent(type);
    }
}
}
```

Then in renderer:

```
dispatchEvent(new MyEvent(MyEvent.SOME_ACTION_PERFORMED));
```

And in class which contains your `Tree`:

```
private function onInit():void
{
    addEventListener(MyEvent.SOME_ACTION_PERFORMED, someActionHandler);
}

private function someActionHandler(event:MyEvent):void
{
    // Perform necessary actions here
    …
    // Then stop bubbling
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
}
```

Comment: This will not work. Tree elements (as ItemRenderer class) are dinamilcaly created and nobody is adding an event Listener to the tree items. Your "someActionHandler" method will never be called.

Comment: `dispatchEvent(new MyEvent(MyEvent.SOME_ACTION_PERFORMED));` is calling from within dynamically added item renderers and so events are propagating up through display list. And if we subscribe it in one of the parent containers we can handle this event. What's the problem

Comment: Just read about [event propagation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7cdb.html). It is a common practice with item renderers and handling events from them.

Comment: will i be able to pass the event as a parameter to Tree object inside the MXML ?

Comment: What do you mean "pass event as parameter"? You can handle event (which can incapsulate some event data) within component and then use this additional data in event object the way you like. BTW the best way to use bubbling events from item renderer is to extend your tree, subscribe to event in your tree's constructor and the either handle event inside your tree or translate it to the "usual" event from your tree with possibility to provide corresponding `[Event]` metadata to have possibility to subscribe event in MXML attribute the way you described in your question.

Comment: But you can't subscribe this custom bubbling event in Tree's attribute (in MXML) with unmodified tree.

Comment: In class which extends Tree i mean ( my bad that i didnt mention it before )

Comment: I described above how you can extend `Tree` and convert bubbling event to usual custom event with corresponding metadata in your `Tree` class.

Comment: oooops ... anoter interesting topic i might not read about - this [Event], blah .. alot of new things to be learned ... I like it :D Thank you :) i will read about thoose things now :)

Comment: You can read it [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf684f9-7ff1.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf684f9-7fef)

Comment: Once more Kick A** example !! :)